DNS Cpanel - FLutter
im with one doubt in my conn between flutter and the cpanel, (its the 1st time working with this) and i didnt know how can i connect the both thinks I think that should be from the url of the folder that i hve created but I have no sure... I will let some photos and code, and I hope someone could help me :D
  //DNS servidor String ip = "http://backend.moneymind.pt:3306";
and the method im calling like this: 'var url = "http://$ip/arquivos/MoneyMind_DBconnection/Login/login.php";
'

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
